# Branching construct based on the (babel) language selected

Tags: macros, conditionals, babel

I'd like to keep one of my presentations in German and English and have defined a corresponding boolean variable with`ifthen` and a command to typeset either the German or the English text.

Is there an easy way to evaluate the global options (\documentclass[**ngerman**]{article}) one defines for e.g. `babel`?

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{mothertongue}
\setboolean{mothertongue}{true}

\newcommand{\tr}[2]{\ifthenelse{\boolean{mothertongue}}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\tr{Deutsch}{English}


\end{document}
```

Based on egregs comment I updated my example, however I get only the English text.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ifthen,babel}
\newcommand{\tr}[2]{\ifthenelse{\equal{\languagename}{ngerman}}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\tr{deutsch}{english}

\languagename

\end{document}
```

Comment: Babel maintains the main language name in `\bbl@main@language` and the current name is available as `\languagename`. You can also look at http://tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/gregorio/

Comment: Looks like an excellent idea, so far it's not working. Based on the `ifthen` documentation `\equal` should do thecorrect comparison.

Comment: Unfortunately, by technical reasons, `\languagename` has category code problems; look at the `iflang` package by Heiko Oberdiek that wasn't available when I wrote that paper.

Comment: That's the most convenient solution, if you make it an answer I'd be happy to accept.

Comment: And don't use `\iflanguage` either, because it compares languages in the TeX sense, ie, hyphenation patterns.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A test `\ifthenelse{\equal{\languagename}{ngerman}}{Deutsch}{English}` can't work for several reasons: first, `\languagename` wouldn't get expanded; but even if we added the suitable number of `\expandafter` tokens, it wouldn't work again, because the expansion of `\languagename` consists of category code 12 characters.

Rather than doing complicated tricks, it's better to load one of the many packages by Heiko Oberdiek, in this case `iflang`; in its documentation the problem is explained.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{iflang}

\newcommand{\tr}{\IfLanguageName{ngerman}{Deutsch}{English}}


\begin{document}
\tr

\selectlanguage{english}
\tr

\end{document}
```

This prints

> Deutsch
>   English

Answer (score 2):

Use pdfTeX's `\pdfstrcmp` primitive for comparison:

[image]

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}% http://ctan.org/pkg/KOMA-script
\usepackage{babel}%  http://ctan.org/pkg/babel
\newcommand{\tr}[2]{\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\languagename}{ngerman}=0 #1\else #2\fi}

\begin{document}

\tr{deutsch}{english}

\languagename

\end{document}
```