# Polyglossia multi-language - wrong fonts used?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, polyglossia

I'm trying to set up a document with Polyglossia/XeLaTeX, which should be mostly in Hebrew, with some English excerpts. However, I can't get fontspec to use the correct English font for anything other than the main (roman) font - it instead uses the Hebrew-specified fonts.

Here is my minimal example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\makeatletter

\setmainfont[Language=English,Script=Latin]{Nimbus Roman No9 L}
\setsansfont[Language=English,Script=Latin]{Nimbus Sans L}
\setmonofont[Language=English,Script=Latin]{Nimbus Mono L}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Language=Hebrew,Script=Hebrew,Scale=3.0]{Frank Ruehl CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Language=Hebrew,Script=Hebrew,Scale=3.0]{Nachlieli CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Language=Hebrew,Script=Hebrew,Scale=3.0]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\makeatother

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
בדיקה, באיזה פונט זה יוצג \textenglish{\ttfamily{Hello, World!}}.


\begin{english}
Hello, \sffamily{Sans}, \ttfamily{Mono}
\end{english}

\end{document}
```

Hebrew fonts scale to better see outcome. The result looks like this:

[image: Picture of outcome PDF]

As you can see, only the default (roman) English font is used, while all other English text uses the scaled (Hebrew) fonts. I have tried with or without Language/Script specifications, but results are always the same.

*Edit:* Changing it so English is default and Hebrew is other seems to fix it, but this is far from ideal - the document would be 95% Hebrew at least. But maybe it hints towards the root cause?

*Edit2:* Changing default language to English also has the undesired outcome of making it so Hebrew Sans-Serif and Typewriter/Mono text disappears completely.

*Edit3:* The proposed fix in Ulrike Fischer's answer has the side effect of making it so after the first use of `\textenglish`, all section titles are wrongly rendered using the English fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\newfontfamily\englishfontsf{TeX Gyre Heros}
\newfontfamily\englishfonttt{TeX Gyre Cursor}

\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\makeatletter 
\addto\inlineextras@english{\xpg@set@normalfont{english}}
\addto\blockextras@english{\xpg@set@normalfont{english}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\section{חלק ראשון}
נכתוב באנגלית \textenglish{Hello, World!}
ומעכשיו כל הכותרות לא יופיעו
\section{חלק שני}
הכותרת לא מופיעה, אבל הטקסט כן.

\end{document}
```

Which results in:
[image: Section titles rendered with wrong fonts]

Different fonts will have different behaviors - the previously used Nimbus fonts only show spaces, while the Liberation ones show empty squares - I guess it has to do with what those fonts have in the Hebrew glyph locations.

Comment: [Is this the desired result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YkuZe.png)?

Comment: The desired result if for the correct fonts (based on language) to be used. The scaling was only done so it is clearly visible that the wrong font specs are used.

Comment: Please don't make example with unusual fonts. I don't want to have to adapt your code before being able to test it.

Comment: Sorry, they are pretty common for Hebrew, you can get them at http://culmus.sourceforge.net/, but I'll adapt the example to the DejaVu fonts.

Comment: I edited the answer. Btw: you should notify me with @UlrikeFischer if you answer me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hebrew is your main language and so it would feel like a hack to set english to the default language only to get the fonts right.

Imho there is a bug in polyglossia, it doesn't seem to reset the fonts correctly.

The following seems to work to correct the problem. As I don't have your fonts I had to change them.

### Edit

As noted in the comment my first solution broke the fonts in \section (and other places). The reason is that `\xpg@set@normalfont` redefines `\normalfont` globally. The following correct this, but it could have other side effects. 
Also it is more a work-around than a solution.

On the whole I think that the font changing commands in polyglossia are not symmetric. There is code for the case "latin=main, hebrew=other" but not the other way round.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}    
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\newfontfamily\englishfontsf{TeX Gyre Heros}
\newfontfamily\englishfonttt{TeX Gyre Cursor}

\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\makeatletter
\def\xpg@set@normalfont#1{%
  \letcs{\rmfamily}{#1@font@rm}%
  \letcs{\sffamily}{#1@font@sf}%
  \letcs{\ttfamily}{#1@font@tt}%
  \def\normalfont{\protect\xpg@select@fontfamily{#1}}%def instead of gdef
  \gdef\reset@font{\protect\normalfont}%
}
\addto\inlineextras@english{\xpg@set@normalfont{english}}
\addto\blockextras@english{\xpg@set@normalfont{english}}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
\section{חלק ראשון}
נכתוב באנגלית \textenglish{Hello, World!}
ומעכשיו כל הכותרות לא יופיעו

\begin{english}
blub \sffamily blub \ttfamily blb
\end{english}


\section{חלק שני}
הכותרת לא מופיעה, אבל הטקסט כן.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, not perfect yet - this seems to make section titles set in Hebrew to try render with the English fonts, which just gives out blocks. I'll try to get a minimal example, but it may have something to do with hyperref.

Comment: Hyperref is not to blame - the proposed fix makes it so after the first use of English text, all section, subsection etc. titles are set with the English fonts.

Comment: Ok, I guess that's the best that can be reasonably done without fixing the bug(s) in polyglossia. I don't yet know enough about the inner working of (Xe)LaTeX to feel comfortable describing what the bug is, but I may try to look into it and file a bug report at a later occasion.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `\sffamilylatin` and `\ttfamilylatin` will help a lot if the main language is non-Latin (page 6 of `polyglossia` documentation). We can then conditionally re-define `\sffamily` and `\ttfamily` to use these `latin` versions by checking if the active language is English, with `\IfLanguageName{english}{true part}{false part}`.

(I had previous used `\iflanguage`, but later found out that its use is [discouraged](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131928/branching-construct-based-on-the-babel-language-selected#comment298114_131928), and `\IfLanguageName` from the `iflang` package is [preferred](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131948/226).)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{iflang}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}

% I don't actually which Hebrew fonts counts as serif or sans serif...
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Language=Hebrew,Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Language=Hebrew,Script=Hebrew]{Miriam CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Language=Hebrew,Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{FreeSerif}
\newfontfamily\sffamilylatin{FreeSans}
\newfontfamily\ttfamilylatin{FreeMono}

% Conditionally redefine \sffamily, \ttfamily to use
% \sffamilylatin, \ttfamilylatin if active language is english
\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\oldttfamily\ttfamily
  \let\oldsffamily\sffamily
  \renewcommand{\ttfamily}{\IfLanguageName{english}{\ttfamilylatin}{\oldttfamily}}
  \renewcommand{\sffamily}{\IfLanguageName{english}{\sffamilylatin}{\oldsffamily}}
}

\begin{document}
בדיקה, באיזה פונט זה יוצג
\textsf{בדיקה, באיזה פונט זה יוצג}

\section{חלק ראשון}

נכתוב באנגלית \textenglish{Hello, World!}
ומעכשיו כל הכותרות לא יופיעו

\begin{english}
blub \sffamily blub \ttfamily blub \textsf{blub} \texttt{blub}
\end{english}


\section{חלק שני}
הכותרת לא מופיעה, אבל הטקסט כן.
\end{document}
```

Example project: https://www.overleaf.com/5971027jytqjd#/19831055/

Comment: Hmm... This is problematic when used in LyX, because LyX automatically uses `\textsf`, `\texttt` etc. Is there a simple way of telling it to use `\xxfamilylatin` only inside an English environment?

Comment: Turns out we can use `\iflanguage` to check for the current active language and conditionally re-define `\sffamily` and `\ttfamily`. I've updated the code sample; this compiles for me fine in XeLaTeX but I don't have LyX to try it out.

Comment: Hmm... For some reason this makes `xelatex` go into an infinite loop for me.

Comment: sorry I had a typo on the `\setmonofont` line. And this seems to work in TL2015 but not TL2016... I'll have another look later

Comment: This is now working for me in both TL2015 and 2016. (I'm using another set of Hebrew fonts different from your example)

Comment: Turns out I put the `\renewcommand` before loading `polyglossia`, which is bound to cause trouble. Not it compiles but I'm still having trouble getting it to work with LyX's `\textxx`, rather than `\xxfamily`. I'll see if I can make a minimal non-LyX document exhibiting this, or maybe I'll find my error while trying.

Comment: I included a `\textsf` in my code sample to test exactly that (it should pick up `\sffamily`), and it looks to be working.