# Chapter title number and name are not typed with English font

Tags: xetex, fontspec, polyglossia, hebrew

I have a document written in both English and Hebrew. For some reason, English chapters title, number and name are not typed in the font I declared for English language text (Latin Modern Roman), but rather in the font set up for Hebrew.

Why is that?

Colors are added for visualization purpose.

```latex
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8

\documentclass[openany,a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia,xcolor}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Latin Modern Roman}[
    Script=Latin, 
    Language=English,
    Ligatures=TeX,
    Color=red]
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}[
    Script=Hebrew, 
    Color=blue]

\begin{document}
\chapter{פרק ראשון}
טקסט טקסט טקסט.
\begin{english}
\chapter{this should be in Latin Modern}
Like this one is.
\end{english}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This might or might not be useful to you, but ``babel` with the `bidi` and `layout=sectioning.tabular` commands should be able to handle this. If you add `babeltags`, your document should be backward-compatible with `\begin{english}` or `\texthebrew`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with `polyglossia`. I found a solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325833/113546) but it seemed incomplete. It adds font switching commands to the language switching command, but it didn't do that when you end a language environment, e.g. at `\end{english}`. I added that code, so that it sets up the language outside of the `english` environment, which normally should be `hebrew`. The scheme will probably not work with more complicated nested environments.

```
\documentclass[openany,a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia,xcolor}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Latin Modern Roman}[
    Script=Latin, 
    Language=English,
    Ligatures=TeX,
    Color=red]
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}[
    Script=Hebrew, 
    Color=blue]

% Add correction code, inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325833/113546
\makeatletter
\def\xpg@set@normalfont#1{%
  \letcs{\rmfamily}{#1@font@rm}%
  \letcs{\sffamily}{#1@font@sf}%
  \letcs{\ttfamily}{#1@font@tt}%
  \def\normalfont{\protect\xpg@select@fontfamily{#1}}%def instead of gdef
  \def\reset@font{\protect\normalfont}%
}
\addto\inlineextras@english{\xpg@set@normalfont{english}}
\addto\blockextras@english{\xpg@set@normalfont{english}}
% Switch back explicitely to previous language
% This should normally be 'hebrew' outside 'english'.
\addto\endenglish{\selectlanguage{\babelname}}
\addto\inlineextras@hebrew{\xpg@set@normalfont{hebrew}}
\addto\blockextras@hebrew{\xpg@set@normalfont{hebrew}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{פרק ראשון}
טקסט טקסט טקסט.
\begin{english}
\chapter{this should be in Latin Modern}
Like this one is.
\chapter{Another test}
Some other text.
\end{english}

\chapter{פרק ארבע}
  טקסט טקסט טקסט.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well done. I am too a novice Texnician to truly understand what `xpg` and `letcs` do, but I think I get the idea.

Comment: I forgot to take out the `\show\endotherlanguage`. It was there for debugging. And after a `\show` TeX signals an error which really isn't an error.